# EF 6 stores nulls in columns that have a default value

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL Server 2014 table with 2 `datetime` columns (`CreateDate` and `ModifyDate`) defined with a default date as shown here:

```
CREATE TABLE [PurchaseOrder].[PurchaseOrder] 
(
    [PurchaseOrderId] int IDENTITY(500,1) NOT NULL,
    [VendorId] int NOT NULL,
    [CreditTerms] nvarchar(128) NULL,
    [PurchasingAgent] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
    [SalesPerson] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
    [TotalBeforeTax] decimal (12, 4) DEFAULT 0,
    [Tax] decimal (12, 4) DEFAULT 0,
    [TotalWithTax] decimal (12, 4) DEFAULT 0,
    [Comments] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [CreateDate] DATETIME2 NULL,
    [ModifyDate] DATETIME2 NULL
);

ALTER TABLE [PurchaseOrder].[PurchaseOrder] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_PurchaseOrderCreateDT DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR CreateDate
go

ALTER TABLE [PurchaseOrder].[PurchaseOrder] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_PurchaseOrderModifyDT DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR ModifyDate
go
```

I am using Entity Framework 6 to update this table. For some reason the `ModifyDate` column is not creating a default date on inserts. Below is the C# code for the Entity Framework insert:

```
static public int AddNewPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrderViewModel aPurchaseOrderViewModel)
{
    PurchaseOrder aPurchaseOrderToAdd = new PurchaseOrder();

    using (RgmSiteDAL RgmSiteDALCtx = new RgmSiteDAL())
    {
        using (DbContextTransaction transaction = RgmSiteDALCtx.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.VendorId = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.VendorId;
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.CreateDate = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.CreateDate;
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.CreditTerms = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.CreditTerms;
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.PurchasingAgent = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.PurchasingAgent;
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.SalesPerson = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.SalesPerson;
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.TotalBeforeTax = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.TotalBeforeTax;
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.Tax = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.Tax;
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.TotalWithTax = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.TotalWithTax;
                aPurchaseOrderToAdd.Comments = aPurchaseOrderViewModel.Comments;

                RgmSiteDALCtx.PurchaseOrder.Add(aPurchaseOrderToAdd);

                RgmSiteDALCtx.SaveChanges(); //save parent PurchaseOrder object

                int PurchaseOrderIdentityIdIssued = aPurchaseOrderToAdd.PurchaseOrderId;
```

The record is inserted without any errors but the `ModifyDate` column is null instead of having the current datetime issued from the `getdate()` function assigned in the alter table statement. I don't know if there is a problem with the way I setup the default datetime for the table or if there is something extra I need to do for an entity that has datetime values that are to be automatically created by the database. There is no datetime value assigned for the `ModifyDate` in the entity because because I was hoping SQL Server would generate the current date as the default. There is a date assigned to the `CreateDate` on inserts from the web application.

The edmx file in the ASP.NET MVC application defines the 2 dates as follows:

```
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifyDate { get; set; }
```

I would appreciate any comments that may help me to find out why the `ModifyDate` column is not getting the current date assigned to it and how to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `null` is still a value. If you try to store an entity whose `CreateDate` or `ModifyDate` are null, you'll get those values in the database. If you want those columns to get their values from the database only, you'll have to mark the properties as [DatabaseGenerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You'll also have to add an AFTER UPDATE trigger to set the `ModifyDate` each time the row is modified

Comment: I'm getting some errors trying to decorate the datetime fields with those attributes. I think I'll just make this simple and use the web server date by calling the DateTime.Now function from the MVC controller and assign that date to the ModifyDate column on inserts. Thanks for your info.

Comment: I see you are using the `DATETIME2` data type - **good choice!** At the same time, I'd also recommend to stop using `GETDATE()` and instead use `SYSDATETIME()` which returns the full precision that `DATETIME2` can handle

Comment: you have to make sure in your model specifies that those columns are "store generated" or "identity"